# Flask apply filter with multiple checkboxes

Tags: python, html, flask

Hey good people of stackoverflow,

My application randomly selects a recipe from MongoDB (using pymongo) and displays it to the user.

My intention is to be able to apply filters (vegetarian, fish, beef and so on) to the next "random" selection after hitting **Something else** button.

I think I can achieve it by using `request.form.getlist` and creating the form in the `pick_meal.html` but it feels a bit overkill.

So far I am unable to figure it out.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The html and python function looks like this:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <h3>{% block title %} You should cook: {% endblock %}</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 align-self-center text-center">
        <span>{{ dish.dish_name }}</span>
        </br>
        </br>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="{{ dish['dish_source'] }}" role="button">Go to web</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="{{ dish.dish_image }}" width="250px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <a href="{{ url_for('pick_meal', dish_type=dish_type) }}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Something else</button></a>
        <a href="{{ url_for('confirm', dish_id=dish['_id']) }}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Configrm choice</button></a>
        <a href="{{ url_for('already_cooked', dish_id=dish['_id'], dish_type=dish_type) }}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Already cooked</button></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="vegetarian" id="flexCheckDefault" name="property_checkbox">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">Vegetarian</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="grill" id="flexCheckDefault" name="property_checkbox">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">Grill</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

```py
@app.route('/pick_meal/<string:dish_type>')
def pick_meal(dish_type):
    # pick random meal based on category
    dish = list(coll.aggregate([
        {'$match':{
            'cooked': False,
            'dish_type': dish_type}},
        { '$sample':{
            'size': 1 } }]))[0]
    return render_template('pick_meal.html', dish=dish, dish_type=dish_type)
```

Comment: `<button>` and `<input>` have to be inside `<form action="url" method="POST"> </form>` to get it as `request.form`

Comment: thanks @furas! I did´t know about `<form action="url">` option.

Comment: it is not option, it is obligatory element :) And it needs `method="POST"` because without `method` it uses `method="GET"` and it sends data in url `https://url/&property_checkbox=true`

Comment: I don't have much experience with html so I am just trying to clarify it for myself. I have only <form method="POST"> (without `action` element) in another template and it is working as expected. However, the form is constructed with wtforms and has `form.submit(class="btn btn-primary")` which, perhaps substitutes the `action` element?

Comment: `form` may automatically put all in `<form></form>`. And `form.submit()` only adds `<button type="submit">` which sends data to server - but only if it is inside `<form></form>`